# Case statement with null values for MySQL

Tags: mysql, null, case

In MYSQL, I have a sales table with `sales.id` and industry table with `primary_industry` and `secondary_industries` in the same column which differentiate by `industry_id`. The logic is (`CASE WHEN cl.industry_id IS NULL THEN cl.industry END` ). For each `sales_id` there might be multiple primary industries and the requirement is to get all the primary industries per `sales_id`. for example  If I have one sales_id with two primary industries I need to get two rows for that.

I am using a case statement but instead of two rows I am getting three rows one with a null row

```
SELECT sales.id as sales_id, a.id as app_id, 
( CASE WHEN cl.industry_id IS NULL THEN cl.industry END ) AS primary_industry
FROM sales 
LEFT JOIN classification_jobs cj on cj.jobref = sales.id 
LEFT JOIN sales_industry cl on cl.id = cj.label_id 
WHERE sales.id in (31271403) 
GROUP BY sales_id, app_id, primary_industry
```

when trying above code I am getting three rows with two rows with two primary industries and the third one with a null primary industry value. but I want exclude the null value row. I can't use `having priamry_industry is not null` option as we have data with sales.id with out industry values at all and if I use `having priamry_industry is not null` then it will exclude the ids with out industries.

I tried creating subquery as a column but I am getting the following error `reference primary_industry not supported (forward reference in items list)` Please help me out in solving the issue

Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired result [mre]

Comment: `CASE WHEN cl.industry_id IS NULL THEN cl.industry END` will return cl.industry when cl.industry_id is NULL, and will return NULL when cl.industry_id is NOT NULL. Add ELSE part to the CASE function.

Comment: Hi @Akina I used your suggestion and names those specific null as 'NO industry' but I am not sure how to remove it from the table. If I use having it is removing the null sales_id rows with out primary_industry